# Configure SharePoint 2010 site to use https

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, ssl, https

I have an existing SharePoint 2010 Foundation site. I am using claims authentication with a custom token provider. It current runs using http. I would like to use a cert to run on https. I already have an SSL cert. My concern is that I have permissions setup on on document libraries and documents. Everything I have read online mentions to extend the current web application. What happens to all the document libary/document permissions on the extended application? Will they be moved over? Is there a way to configure my current site to use https without extending it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you dont need to extend the web app rather you have to update the IIS bindings.

On the WFE servers, Add the Binding for the SSL & attach the certs.

Now update the Https entry into the AAM via Central Admin.

check this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmyancs/archive/2010/02/12/how-to-enable-ssl-on-a-sharepoint-web-application.aspx

Comment: Just a quick comment, here's a link to a guide with pretty pictures. Waqas Sarar above's information should be quite correct. http://www.virtualsecrets.com/misc_imgs/sharepoint-2010/adding-ssl-certificate.html